# Email delivery failure in php mail function

Tags: php, email, sendmail

I use PHP mail() function to send emails. Is it possible to found out if the email is sent or failed ?

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible to determine if the email was received: Email is not a guaranteed delivery mechanism.

Unless you include some sort of  response link in your email that the recipient must click on, then No.

Comment: Usually, if an email failed to send to a valid email address, then a Delivery Failed Notification will be delivered.

Answer (score 1):

try including X-Failed-Recipients: << email >>

Answer (score 0):

The PHP Mail function returns a boolean value. Thus you can easily know if the mail was accepted for the delivery. But you cannot know if it was sent or not by the Mail Server (SMTP)

```
bool mail ( string $to , string $subject , string $message [, string $additional_headers [, string $additional_parameters ]] )
```

> Returns TRUE if the mail was successfully accepted for delivery, FALSE
>   otherwise.
>
> It is important to note that just because the mail was accepted for
>   delivery, it does NOT mean the mail will actually reach the intended
>   destination.

Link: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Code

```
if(mail(...)){ ... }
else{ ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible without checking the mailer logs. The mail function only returns `true` if the mailer accepted your mail but doesn't give you information if the mail has been received by your recipient.

> Returns TRUE if the mail was successfully accepted for delivery, FALSE
>   otherwise.
>
> It is important to note that just because the mail was accepted for delivery, it does NOT mean the mail will actually reach the
>   intended destination.

[See here.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

Answer (score 0):

Here you are... basic sending emails with PHPmailer:

```
if(!$mail->Send()){
   echo "Emails Sending Failed!";
}else{
   echo "Emails Successfully Sent!";
}
```

For finding extra failure msg, add-on following code will help...

```
echo $mail->ErrorInfo;
```